# HTML video tag autoplay in Safari without user interaction

Tags: html, video, safari, autoplay

I have autoplay in the video tag, but it still requires mousing over it.  From what I read it's because it requires user interaction to play the video, so users won't be annoyed by videos playing without their consent.  Is there a way to get around that or fake the event well enough to fool the browser?

Comment: autoplay is becoming more supported as long as the video is muted, but if you un-mute without user intervention then the video will pause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. And if there was a way to fool it, Apple would just close that loophole on the next release.