# How do I get my A-FRAME video to load in HTML?

Tags: html, aframe

I have the following HTML code (just for reference of what im doing):

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.3/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system/v4.0.1/dist/aframe-physics-system.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/donmccurdy/aframe-extras@v6.1.0/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-environment-component@1.1.0/dist/aframe-environment-component.min.js"></script>
    <a-scene physics="debug: true">
        <a-assets>
      <img crossorigin="anonymous" id="sky" src="sky.png">
      <video crossorigin="anonymous" id="penguin-sledding" autoplay loop="true" src='penguin-sledding.mp4'></video>
    </a-assets>
      <a-sky src="#sky"></a-sky>
      <a-video src="#penguin-sledding" width="16" height="9" position="0 0 -1"></a-video>
      <a-entity id="rig" jump-ability="distance: 1.8;" movement-controls kinematic-body="enableJumps: true;">
        <a-entity id="camera" look-controls="pointerLockEnabled: true;" camera position="0 1.6 0"></a-entity>
      </a-entity>

      <!-- Floor -->
      <a-plane static-body material="color: grey" width="25" height="25" rotation="-90 0 0" position="0 0 0"></a-plane>

      <a-box id='b' width="10" velocity='0, 0, 0' height="5" depth="0.5" static-body material="color: lightblue" position="0 0 -5"></a-box>
      <a-box width="10" height="5" depth="0.5" static-body material="color: lightblue" position="0 0 5"></a-box>
    </a-scene>
  </head>
</html>
```

and if you were to try to play this the video (a black widescreen) would just be pure black. If i am currently running the code and i update the video source (even if i update it to the same thing), it will start loading the video. Any idea why my video wont load along with everything else?

Comment: pc / mac / android / ios ?

Comment: pc (window surface using Brackets software)

Comment: most browsers today have disabled autoplay. you need a user gesture (like a button click) to start video playback. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57542229/autoplaying-videosphere-from-a-frame-is-not-working-on-any-browsersafari-chrome